# Obtener maximo en un array object JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código donde creo un *array* de objetos con cantidades.

Deseo saber el que tiene mayor cantidad y sacar el código de ese.

Ejemplo: Con este código obtengo la cantidad máxima, pero me gustaría en vez que entregue cantidad entregue el código.

```js
var array_data = [];

array_data.push({
  "codigo": '1',
  "cantidad": '2',
  "code": '001',
});

array_data.push({
  "codigo": '2',
  "cantidad": '7',
  "code": '002',
});

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array_data.map(function(o) {return o.cantidad;}))

console.log(max);

/* Obtengo el valor maximo en cantidad, pero quiero saber a que codigo es esa cantidad.

Resultado seria codigo: 2 */
```

Comment: tu pregunta es algo dudosa. Puedes editar y colocar un ejemplo de lo que esperas?

Comment: @JeanGotopo Listo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citando el comentario del código:

> Obtengo el valor maximo en cantidad, pero quiero saber a qué código es esa cantidad. Resultado seria código: 2

Ya has conseguido lograr parte de ese trabajo, solo tienes agregar la siguiente línea:

```javascript
array_data.find((value) => Number(value.cantidad) === max).codigo;
```

Por lo tanto, si la implementamos obtendríamos lo siguiente:

```js
// Observe que este fragmento es exactamente lo que has hecho. Sin ningún cambio:
var array_data = [];

array_data.push({
  codigo: "1",
  cantidad: "2",
  code: "001",
});

array_data.push({
  codigo: "2",
  cantidad: "7",
  code: "002",
});
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array_data.map(function (o) {return o.cantidad;}));

// Lo nuevo está acá:
const maxCode = {
  max,
  codigo: array_data.find((value) => Number(value.cantidad) === max).codigo,
};

console.log( maxCode );
```

Lo nuevo está en el siguiente fragmento:

```javascript
const maxCode = {
  max,
  codigo: array_data.find((value) => Number(value.cantidad) === max).codigo,
};

console.log(maxCode);
```

Sin embargo, es mejor obtener todo el objeto completo correspondiente al valor obtenido, por ejemplo:

```javascript
const maxCode = {
  ...array_data.find((value) => Number(value.cantidad) === max)
};
```

Si la implementamos completa tendríamos el siguiente fragmento completo:

```js
// Observe que este fragmento es exactamente lo que has hecho. Sin ningún cambio:
var array_data = [];

array_data.push({
  codigo: "1",
  cantidad: "2",
  code: "001",
});

array_data.push({
  codigo: "2",
  cantidad: "7",
  code: "002",
});
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array_data.map(function (o) {return o.cantidad;}));

// Lo nuevo está acá:
const maxCode = {
  ...array_data.find((value) => Number(value.cantidad) === max)
};

console.log( maxCode );
```

De manera que puedas utilizarlo así:

```javascript
console.log( maxCode.cantidad, maxCode.codigo);
```

Comment: Tal vez se podría simplificar usando solo un método (reduce) para obtener el objeto que tenga la cantidad mayor, de ahí se pueden obtener todos los datos. Buena respuesta. +1

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta :).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero encontre una mas simple `const max = array_data.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev.total > current.total) ? prev : current
});`

Answer (score 0):

si lo que deseas es que te devuelva el código de mayor valor, puedes utilizar la misma función que tienes, pero cambiando el parámetro que buscas:

```
var maxCantidad  = Math.max.apply(Math, array_data.map(function(o) { return o.cantidad; }))
var maxCode  = Math.max.apply(Math, array_data.map(function(o) { return o.codigo; }))

console.log(maxCantidad); //devuelve 7
console.log(maxCode); //devuelve 2
```

Answer (score 0):

yo cree esta función que puede ser de ayuda en esos casos

```js
let carrer = [{
  id: 3,
  cicle: 200,
}, {
  id: 33,       
  cicle: 44,
}]
  const getIdOfMaxCicle = (array: any[] = [], property: string ="id", initialValue: number = 0) =>{
    return  array.reduce(
      (max, character) => (
        character[property] > max[property] ? 
        {...character, [property]:character[property]} : 
        max
      ),
      {[property]: initialValue}
    );
  }
  console.log(getIdOfMaxCicle(carrer, "cicle"))
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).